# Сравнение нескольких параметров

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if

Cтолкнулся со следующей проблемой : Необходимо реализовать проверку каждой входящей переменной (дважды), в случае числового, то на нахождения в недиапазоне от меньше N до больше M, в случае текстового, то просто либо Null, либо Empty.String. Пытался реализовать при помощи if, также пытался писать case с условием выполнения, но обнаружил, что необходима версия 9.0 .
Проблема начинается с того, что при вводе значений типа (1,1, "november") или (2,10, "april") метод начинает выдавать ошибку. Хотелось бы понять, что не так сделано

```
public static string Date (int day, int month, string year)
{
    if (day < 1 | day > 31)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(day));
    }
    if (month < 1 | month > 12)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(month));
    }
    else if (year == null && year == string.Empty)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(year));
    }
    else 
    {
        return year;   
    }
}
```

Comment: "метод начинает выдавать ошибку" - ??

Comment: Опечатеа. Замените `|` на `||` в условиях. Еще можете убрать все `else`, они лишние.

Comment: @Igor , в смысле метод работает некорректно)

Comment: Что значит "метод работает некорректно" известно только Вам.

Comment: Лучше такое проверять через `string.IsNullOrEmpty(year)`

Comment: @Igor , и в правду только мне, но проблема была решена, но она как оказывается касалось не этого участка кода, за отзывчивость благодарю)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
else if (year == null || year == string.Empty)
                      ^^
```